# Image processing in a multhithreaded mode using Java

Tags: java, image-processing, concurrency

I am supposed to process images in a multithreaded mode using Java. I may having varying number of images where as my number of threads are fixed. I have to process all the images using the fixed set of threads.

I am just stuck up on how to do it, I had a look ThreadExecutor and BlockingQueues etc...I am still not clear. What I am doing is,
- Get the images and add them in a LinkedBlockingQueue which has runnable code of the image processor.
- Create a threadpoolexecutor for which one of the arguements is the LinkedBlockingQueue earlier.
- Iterate through a for loop till the queue size and do a threadpoolexecutor.execute(linkedblockingqueue.poll).
- all i see is it processes only 100 images which is the minimum thread size passed in LinkedBlockingQueue size.

I see I am seriously wrong in my understanding somewhere, how do I process all the images in sets of 100(threads) until they are all done? Any examples or psuedocodes would be highly helpful

Thanks!
J

Comment: I updated my post with some sample code. It is not perfect just a quick stab at it. It runs completely self contained.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a sample class that I wrote. The whole thing runs standalone and prints a number from 1 to 100 each from a ThreadPool. Pretty much all you need to do is update the Request class to pass in what you want and to re-implement ImageProcessor.

```
package com.rch.test;

import java.util.concurrent.BlockingQueue;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class Executor
{
    /**
     * Class to encapsulate a request
     * 
     * @author romain
     */
    static class Request
    {
        String someText;

        Request(String someText)
        {
            this.someText = someText;
        }

        public String getSomeText()
        {
            return someText;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Creates a Thread that listens on a queue to process messages
     * 
     * @author romain
     */
    static class ServerThread implements Runnable
    {
        private BlockingQueue<Request> queue = new LinkedBlockingQueue<Request>();
        boolean stop = false;

        /**
         * Does all the work
         */
        @Override
        public void run()
        {
            ExecutorService pool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(3);
            try
            {
                while (!stop)
                {
                    Request req = queue.poll(1000L, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
                    if (req != null)
                    {
                        Runnable runnable = new Executor.ImageProcessor(req);
                        pool.execute(runnable);
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (InterruptedException ie)
            {
                System.out.println("Log something here");
            }
            finally
            {
                pool.shutdown();
            }
        }

        /**
         * Accepts a message on the queue
         * @param request
         */
        public void accept(Request request)
        {
            queue.add(request);
        }

        public void stopProcessing()
        {
            stop = true;
        }
    }

    /**
     * class to do the actual work
     * @author romain
     */
    static class ImageProcessor implements Runnable
    {
        String someText;

        ImageProcessor(Request req)
        {
            this.someText = req.getSomeText();
        }

        @Override
        public void run()
        {
            System.out.println(someText);
            // Process Image here
        }
    }

    /**
     * Test Harness
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        // Initialize 
        ServerThread processor = new ServerThread();
        Thread aThread = new Thread(processor);
        aThread.start();

        // Wait for Thread to start
        try
        {
            Thread.sleep(500L);
        }
        catch (InterruptedException e1)
        {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        {
            String text = "" + i;
            Request aRequest = new Request(text);
            processor.accept(aRequest);
        }

        // Give it enough time to finish
        try
        {
            Thread.sleep(500L);
        }
        catch (InterruptedException e1)
        {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }

        // Tell the thread to finish processing
        processor.stopProcessing();

        // Wait for the Thread to complete
        try
        {
            aThread.join();
        }
        catch (InterruptedException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sun's tutorials is really good so i will just post the link [Defining and Starting a Thread](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/essential/concurrency/runthread.html)

> Quote:
>   Threads are sometimes called lightweight processes. Both processes and threads provide an execution environment, but creating a new thread requires fewer resources than creating a new process.
>   Threads exist within a process — every process has at least one. Threads share the process's resources, including memory and open files. This makes for efficient, but potentially problematic, communication.

```
while(que is not empty)
  start new set of image-processing-thread
```

Answer (score 0):

You can think of each processing operation being a 'task'.  Place these tasks in a single queue, and have each thread consuming a task from this thread each time they complete a task.